# How to save a CommonsMultipartFile as JPG always (and check if it is an image) in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

It works:

View (GSP):

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="myImageFile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

Controller:

```
def destination = "D:\\someFolder\\image.jpg";
def f = request.getFile('myImageFile')
f.transferTo(new File(destination))
response.sendError(200, 'Done')
```

But **I want to convert it to a JPG image always. So I tried:**

```
def destination = "D:\\someFolder\\image.jpg";
PlanarImage inputfile = JAI.create("FileLoad", f);
JAI.create("filestore",inputfile,destination,"JPEG");
```

This is the error:

*FileLoad - Parameter values class (org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile) is not an instance of the parameter class (java.lang.String) for parameter "filename".. Stacktrace follows:*

So far, the only solution I have though is to save the image as normally after checking if it is an image (thanks @james-kleeh). Then loading it with JAI.create and do the stuff. Finally deleting the original image.

I also wonder how could I **check if the uploaded file is an image**.

Comment: I did some searching: http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

Comment: The data in that site seemed correct based on some quick examples I tried. Seems like a tough solution because of all of the different image types.

Comment: Yes, it look an excelent way to check if it is an image file or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GSP code is the same I posted in the question.

The controller code would be like this:

```
import javax.media.jai.*;
...

def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    def okContentTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif']

if (!okContentTypes.contains(f.getContentType())) { 
    // TODO Tell user: "Image type must be one of: ${okContentTypes}"
}

else {
    def destination = "D:\\someFolder\\image.jpg";
    byte[] source = f.bytes;
    SeekableStream inputStream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(source);
    RenderedOp image = JAI.create("stream", inputStream)
    JAI.create("filestore",image,destination,"JPEG"); // Destination directory must exist (D:\someFolder\)
}
```

I hope it is useful for somebody!

Comment: I am finally using this library: [code.google.com/p/thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/). It is actually good. Take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Following controller side code I use to save uploaded image outside the application.

```
def f = request.getFile('myFile')
def okContentTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif']

if (!okContentTypes.contains(f.getContentType())) { 
    //TODO Tell user: "Image type must be one of: ${okContentTypes}"
} else {
    def destination = "/opt/jft/profileImages"  //path to dir where images will be saved. In my case profileImages is the destination dir.
    File dir = new File(destination)
    dir.mkdirs()
    f.transferTo(new File(dir, f.getOriginalFilename()))
}
```

Here you don't need to have existing destination directory, if it does not exists then program will create it.

Comment: I'll use `File dir = new File(destination)` and
    `dir.mkdirs()`. This code does not save as jpg always though.

Comment: This code save all the images of type mentioned in okContentTypes. Make sure to use last line as well(`f.transferTo(new File(dir, f.getOriginalFilename()))`).

Comment: No. I use my code as it save the images as jpg always. I mean, if the image is a bmp, it will be coverted to jpg before saving.